# NameError name 'request' is not defined when trying to check for cookie -Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies, request

I'm encountering the following problem when I'm trying to check if a cookie exists.

```
import requests




username = raw_input('Please enter your username: ')
password = raw_input('Please enter your password: ')


DATA = {
"url": "http://example.com/index.php",
"action": "do_login",
"submit": "Login",
"quick_login": "1",
"quick_username": (username),
"quick_password": (password),
}

requests.post("http://example.com/member.php", data=DATA)


if 'mybbuser' in request.COOKIES.keys():
                                             print("Correct")

else:
    print("Wrong")
```

The error I'm getting:

NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Comment: `self.request` is trying to find a class instance variable named request in the current class instance.  It doesn't appear that you are using a class.

Comment: I have removed self in the final code, and I'm getting the error:          NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to store the response and look for the cookies there:

```
resp = requests.post(...)
if resp.cookies['blahblah']:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to change it to `requests` instead of `request`.